# Hide SQL in Profiler

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

How can I make my SQL statements not to appear in Profiler ? 
They contain sensitive information and I don't want them to 
show in Profiler.

Thanks for the replies !

Answer (score 4):

The profiler can only be run by someone with proper rights so if your installation is properly secured you should be fine (no users should be able to profile your application).This goes beyond security, since profiler slows down the server considerably.

Comment: This is not always the case.  The scenario where a DBA may have administration rights to the database (for maintenance), however have no right to view sensitive details inside the database.  Encryption/hashing the information is one solution to provide for both scenarios.

Answer (score 3):

Only way I can think of to do this would be to make them stored procedures (The profiler would only show the call), but if the arguments are what's secure (which is likely) then that won't help you (Edit: As pointed out in comments you can change the config of the profiler to include this anyway, so this won't help much)

Have you considered not giving access to people not allowed to view the data? Access to run the profiler is a pretty high level of access...

Also, have you considered [hashing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function) your data before storing/querying it? Sometimes that won't work, but if we're talking passwords then they really should be stored and looked up in an encrypted form anyway.

Comment: Making them stored procedure is not enough since the SP:StmtCompleted event can still be used to trace stored procedures execution (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189570.aspx)

Comment: But that won't show the SQL within the actual stored procedure. As I said it'd only work if it was the SQL itself and not the arguments you needed to protect. (Though in hindsight anyone who has access to run a profiler trace probably has enough to show the definition of a stored procedure)

Comment: No, that **will** show the actual statement being executed, step by step.

Answer (score 3):

There is no way. The "text" column in profiler can not be removed from use.

You need rights to run profiler (sysadmin or `GRANT ALTER TRACE`) so it's not an implicit right.

Note:

- sysadmins could decrypt stored procs or add logging code, regardless of whether they run profiler
- physical access needs controlled, at least to stop someone taking a copy of the database away
- things like sp_password or ALTER LOGIN are not traced anyway

Answer (score 0):

I've noticed if you use the encryption functions build into SQL (Written about at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/encryption/sql-server-encryption?view=sql-server-ver15) like `ENCRYPTBYPASSPHRASE`, the text is not shown in profiler - I'm not sure if this is 100% fool proof but it does fit the question.

Example...
[image]