# Hiding statements from SQL Server Profiler (or other observers)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

In SQL Server 2008 R2, I would like to execute a statement that I want to be invisible to the SQL Profiler or other means of observing user queries. Is there a way to control what is displayed by SQL profiler?

I would like to execute something like:

```
SELECT 'MyPassword' INTO #passwordTable
```

I don't want to show 'MyPassword' through SQL Server Profiler or other means. Any ideas?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Hide SQL in Profiler](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1823886/hide-sql-in-profiler)

Comment: You shouldn't be storing plaintext passwords.

Comment: That question wasn't really answered...

Comment: I am not storing plaintext passwords - it is only on a per session basis. I would like to just keep it around so I can unencrypt some columns if they need to be unencrypted.

Comment: Is there a reason why you aren't using certificates?

Comment: Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63563570/11421

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Essentially, no, you can't. You used to be able to do this by adding a comment like this into the batch or statement:

```
-- sp_password
```

But this no longer works. Why aren't you *hashing* your password?

Comment: I thought about that but I need to use a symmetric key later on and I need to pass it the password so I need to hide the password but I need to give it to sql sever at some point.

Comment: Is there a new way to do it? I see companies like dbDefence are doing it. How are they doing it?

Comment: I'm not familiar with their tool, but they probably encrypt and decrypt (or more likely encode and decode) the data at each end of the pipe. According to their docs: `DbDefence uses an OPEN MASTER KEY statement which is not displayed by the Profiler.` I quite honestly don't think that is relevant to the code you're talking about.

Comment: @AaronBertrand: You're incorrect, this is exactly what I am looking for. Need to figure out how they did it.

Comment: @Denis again, are you sure that the product truly does hide `'SELECT 'MyPassword' INTO #PasswordTable`? Have you tried it? I really do believe they are talking about a different password than a password you happen to include in some query. How would it identify that specific batch as something it needs to encrypt/encode? Do you expect it to encrypt/encode all T-SQL batches? If it does, that should make query troubleshooting fun...

Comment: @Denis I also don't think you should tell me I'm incorrect if you haven't tried it. I'm only challenging your assertion that their product solves your problem exactly.

Comment: @Aaron, I tried it. Their way works. They are able to hide it somehow.

Comment: @Denis great! Now unless they tell you how they did it, I guess you'll have to open your wallet. Because I have absolutely no idea how they can prevent any trace from picking it up.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you have to be a server administrator to run the SQL Profiler, so even if you could prevent it from seeing the command, the user could just go grab the password table anyway.  Ideally you would be storing hashes of the passwords rather than the passwords, making any viewing from the profiler useless.

If you really want to try and keep the profiler from seeing the statements, you could try a third party tool like this: http://www.dbdefence.com/support/dbdefence-documentation/

I have no idea if it works though, or how reputable that company is.

Comment: I wonder how they protect the SQL statements from being shown in profiler. There must be some command to do it or some flag you need to set.

Answer (score 1):

Denis, Aaron is correct, there is nothing like an "invisible statement", you can't tweak SQL Profiler to NOT show statements: once aboard, one can see all statements running in the DB.

You need to obfuscate this sensible data before submitting it to the DB. There are some obfuscated methods available (one-way hash, symmetric algoritms, home-made methods), you need to choose the more suitable method to your needs and implement it. Unfortunatelly, there is no free-lunch to your case...

Comment: Companies like dbdefence do it so there must be a way. Just have to figure out how they do it.

Comment: Denis, DBDefence do its magic by wrapping the SQL Server processes, there is nothing to do with T-SQL. To mimic DBDefence, you must write your own wrapper. Since this is an incredibly complex task, maybe you should consider acquire a copy of DBDefense.

Answer (score 1):

I have seen a product called DBDefence. 
It hides SQL statements from the profiler completely. I do not know how do they do it.
I use free version because I have small database.

In earlier versions of SQL Server it was possible to add a comment --sp_password 
but not in SQL Server 2008 and above.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the point, really. If one is able to view a query with SQL profiler, surely he could access the database to view the actual data.

The key is to not store sensitive data (like passwords) in clear text.

Preventing people to use SQL profiler will come down to applying the proper security configuration on your SQL Server.

Comment: @Denis: you shouldn't *encrypt* passwords but *hash* them.  http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/09/youre-probably-storing-passwords-incorrectly.html

Comment: I need to use a password for the symmetric key down the line. I understand about hashing and encryption. It really depends what you need the password for.

Comment: You shouldn't ever need to decrypt the password.  If the user forgets it, or you need to access their account, reset the password to a new one.

Comment: @Denis - That isn't true anyway. It is possible to view the contents of other session's `#temp` tables using `DBCC PAGE`